# Odd lag with Mitsubishi ASX auto

Tags: automatic-transmission

I was test driving a 2017 model ASX - 2.2 litre auto diesel - and experienced an odd lag at one point.

Having driving other automatics, I understand there's a bit of lag - but this was very unusual.

Basically, I was coming to a stop and pulling over - from about 60 km/h and braking gradually. When I was almost at a stop (maybe about 10 km/h) the salesman suggested I pull in a bit further along, so I took my foot off the brake and then tried to accelerate. The engine simple revved with no power going to the wheels. This lasted several seconds, before I lifted off the gas and then tried again. Same result. On the third go, the power took and we moved forward again.

I'm trying to understand if this is normal for the ASX, or for autos in general (though, I've never experienced it before). One friend suggested it is because of the continual velocity transmission - but the information I can find is that the CVT is only used in petrol vehicles, and this was a diesel auto.

So is this normal? And is it limited to Mitsubishi ASX?

Comment: Have you tried it again since? Or, are you expecting a solution to a "one off" situation that you cannot re-evaluate after taking account of any comments?

Comment: I am trying to find if this might have happened to other people. I am going to try again, too. I will gladly reevaluate after any reasonable comment has actually been made.